# Emotional or Sentimental

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I have read all the dictionaries and surfed the web to find out the nuance between the words: "sentimental" and "emotional", but I'm not able to explain their semantic difference if it comes to!
As a reply to a thread on stackexchange, [mfe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20224/difference-between-sentimental-and-emotional) said:

> Use sentimental to indicate mood, as in someone who reflects on his/her feelings. 
>   Use emotional to indicate someone who reacts to events by expressing what he/she feels. 
>   Sentimental connotes an internalized feeling, emotional an expressive one.

But actually I guess rarely non-native people would be able to use these two words in their correct places based on a simple definition.

So I wonder if you could provide me with some particular examples so that I could distinguish between these two.

Also I read about the adjective "sentimental" that mostly it is used to refer to the past memories.

> A sentimental person is strongly influenced by emotional feelings, especially about happy **memories** of past events or relationships with other people, rather than by careful thought and judgment based on facts.

I would be greateful if you explain that to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

"[Sentiment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentiment)" is a feeling toward a particular event or situation, or toward the past in general (e.g. nostalgia). It generally connotes a more subdued feeling, and something that is deeper and constant.

"[Emotion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emotion)" is more of a temporary or reactionary feeling (e.g. "how I am feeling at this moment"), connoting something more volatile and circumstantial.

By extension, when used to refer to a person, saying that someone is "[sentimental](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sentimental)" means that they have deep feelings about something, generally in a tender or subdued manner (internal).

> **Sentimental**. Expressive of or appealing to sentiment, especially the tender emotions and feelings, as love, pity, or nostalgia

Saying that someone is "[emotional](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/emotional)" generally means that they are prone to outward displays of emotions (external), or perhaps controlled by their feelings.

> **Emotional**. Showing or revealing very strong emotions; subject to or easily affected by emotion; governed by emotion

Comment: Thank you @geekahedron. Somewhere I read calling someone "sentimental" would sound pejorative to Britons! Is it right? To me someone who is in love, or thinks about their past and nostalgies, always is a very interesting and lovely person! What do you think?

Comment: Meanwhile, according to your explanations it seems that a "sentimental" person never displays their true feelings, while an "emotional" person would. Do you agree?

Comment: @A-friend Calling someone or something  emotional or sentimental can have either a positive or negative connotation depending on the context.

Comment: Ah @ColleenV, the distinguishment between these two is really a hard work! How shall I do that, I have no idea! :-?